# C# transparent image above 2 images

Tags: c#, winforms, image, png, transparent

I have make a playbar for my new MP3 player but I have a problem as shown in attachement 
and this is my simple code :

```
 public void setpercent(int percent)
     {
         pic1.Width = pic2.Width / 100 * percent;
         pic3.Left = pic1.Width - ( pic3.Width /2); 

     }
```

I thought to use Graphics but I can't move it after.
and the method of ".Parent" doesn't work in this case.

[image]

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me you're using WinForms.  This will be _much_ easier in WPF.

Comment: Yes, I use WinForms ! But What can I do now ?

Comment: May be I'm strange, but what attachment?

Comment: Also, the method names are flagrant violations of the C# standard. Not to mention the numbered abbreviations, which is wrong in any programming language on this level.

Comment: @user3105622: WinForms controls don't really support transparency.  Use WPF instead.

Comment: @elyashiv It's the picture which explain better th problem  !!

Comment: There is any way to use Graphics for example ?

Comment: Try the code from this article: http://componentfactory.blogspot.hk/2005/06/net2-transparent-controls.html see if it helps

Comment: You're setting yourself for a lot of horrible pain, and a lot of horrible flicker. winforms is a useless deprecated technology that doesn't support any kind of customization. Either use the default, ugly, boring, Windows 3.1 like winforms stuff, or switch to a serious, decent, usable UI technology like WPF that allows at least a level of customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Load() event of your Form, modify the **Region()** property of `pic3` so that it becomes circular instead of rectangular.  This can be done by construction a **GraphicsPath** and adding an Ellipse to it.  If this doesn't line up properly with your image, then manually determine the correct bounding box for the ellipse and use that instead:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath GP = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        GP.AddEllipse(pic3.ClientRectangle);
        pic3.Region = new Region(GP);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much although it isn't in high definition.

Comment: Like the others said, if you want serious graphics manipulation then move on over to WPF.